# Flutter - how to avoid inserting duplicate entries in sqflite database

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

i am new to flutter i am trying to build a news app i am displaying a list of news from json url and when the save icon button is clicked the news is saved to readlater file

when the save icon button is clicked twice then it is adding duplicate entries in database.

how to avoid it

expected result when clicked for the first time it should add the news to readlater and when clicked again it should delete it from the readlater.dart file

thanks in advance.

below is the code where i am saving and displaying the news title and its description(file name is news_detail.dart);

```
class Newsdetail extends StatefulWidget {
  String  value_image, value_description, value_title;
  List value_datalist;
  int value_index;
  String newsId;

  Newsdetail(
      {this.value_image,
        this.value_description,
        this.value_title,
        this.value_datalist,
        this.value_index,
        this.newsId,
      });

  @override
  _newsdetail createState() => _newsdetail(value_title,value_image,value_description,value_datalist,value_index,newsId);
}

class _newsdetail extends State<Newsdetail> {
  String  image, description, title;
  List<News> datalist;
  int v_index;
  bool _isLoaded = false;
  String idNews;
  final dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.instance;

  List<Read> cars = [];

  _newsdetail(this.title,this.image,this.description,this.datalist,this.v_index,this.idNews);
  double custFontSize = 22;
  void increaseFontSize() async{
    setState(() {
      custFontSize+=2;
    });
  }

  void decreaseFontSize() async{
    setState(() {
      custFontSize-=2;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    print(widget.newsId);
  }

  _openFacebook() async {
    //FlutterShareMe().shareToFacebook(url: "https://www.kutchmitradaily.com/article.aspx?news_id="+
    //widget.newsId);
  }

  _openTwitter() async {
    var response = await FlutterShareMe().shareToTwitter(url: "https://www.kutchmitradaily.com/article.aspx?news_id="+
        widget.newsId);
    if (response == 'success') {
      print('navigate success');
    }
  }

  _openWhatsapp(){
    FlutterShareMe()
        .shareToWhatsApp(base64Image: "$image",msg: "$title\n\n" +
        "https://www.kutchmitradaily.com/article.aspx?news_id="+
        widget.newsId + "\n via Kutchmitra App (Download Now):" + "\n https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webpioneer.kutchmitra"
    );
  }

  void _insert(newsId, title, image, description) async {
    Client rnd = Client(newsId: newsId, newsTitle: title, newsImage: image, newsDescription: description);
    await DBProvider.db.newClient(rnd);
    print(newsId);
    print(title);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    onPreviousChange(){
      setState(() {
        image = datalist[widget.value_index-1].image;
        title = datalist[widget.value_index-1].title;
        description = datalist[widget.value_index-1].description;
        v_index = widget.value_index-1;
      });
      widget.value_index = v_index;
    }
    onNextChange(){
      setState(() {
        image = datalist[widget.value_index+1].image;
        title = datalist[widget.value_index+1].title;
        description = datalist[widget.value_index+1].description;
        v_index = widget.value_index+1;
      });
      widget.value_index = v_index;
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: image.isNotEmpty ? Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 10.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(child:
                    Image.network("$image")),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          IconButton(
                              icon: Image.asset('images/facebook.png',),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                              onPressed: () {
                                _openFacebook();
                              }),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Image.asset('images/twitter.png',),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                            onPressed: () {
                              _openTwitter();
                            },
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Image.asset(
                              'images/whatsapp.png', width: 180.0,
                              height: 180.0,),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            onPressed: () {
                              _openWhatsapp();
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,0),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 30,
                            child: FlatButton(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                onPressed: (){
                                  increaseFontSize();
                                },
                                child: Text('A+',style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 22.0,color: Colors.black
                                ),)),
                          ),
                        ),

                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,0),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 40,
                            child: FlatButton(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              onPressed: (){
                                decreaseFontSize();
                              },
                              child: Text('A-',style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0,color: Colors.black
                              ),),

                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,0),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 40,
                            child: FlatButton(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              child: _isLoaded ? IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _isLoaded = false;
                                    });
                                    _insert(widget.newsId,datalist[widget.value_index].title,datalist[widget.value_index].image, datalist[widget.value_index].description);
                                  }
                              ) : IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _isLoaded = true;
                                    });
                                    _insert(widget.newsId,datalist[widget.value_index].title,datalist[widget.value_index].image, datalist[widget.value_index].description);
                                  }
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        "$title",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: custFontSize, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          "$description".replaceAll('<br />', '').replaceAll('\r', '').replaceAll('\n', '').replaceAll('\t', ''),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: custFontSize),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ) : Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0,top: 100.0,right: 8.0,bottom: 8.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          IconButton(
                              icon: Image.asset('images/facebook.png',),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                              onPressed: () {
                                _openFacebook();
                              }),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Image.asset('images/twitter.png',),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                            onPressed: () {
                              _openTwitter();
                            },
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Image.asset(
                              'images/whatsapp.png', width: 180.0,
                              height: 180.0,),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                            onPressed: () {
                              _openWhatsapp();
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,0),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 30,
                            child: FlatButton(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                onPressed: (){
                                  increaseFontSize();
                                },
                                child: Text('A+',style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 22.0,color: Colors.black
                                ),)),
                          ),
                        ),

                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,0),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 40,
                            child: FlatButton(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              onPressed: (){
                                decreaseFontSize();
                              },
                              child: Text('A-',style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15.0,color: Colors.black
                              ),),

                            ),
                          ),
                        ),


                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,0,0),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 40,
                            child: FlatButton(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              child: _isLoaded ? IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _isLoaded = false;
                                    });
                                    _insert(widget.newsId,datalist[widget.value_index].title,datalist[widget.value_index].image, datalist[widget.value_index].description);
                                  }
                              ) : IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _isLoaded = true;
                                    });
                                    _insert(widget.newsId,datalist[widget.value_index].title,datalist[widget.value_index].image, datalist[widget.value_index].description);
                                  }
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Text(
                        "$title",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: custFontSize, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          "$description".replaceAll('<br />', '').replaceAll('\r', '').replaceAll('\n', '').replaceAll('\t', ''),
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: custFontSize),
                        )),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
        ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0.0,
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: AppBar(
              title: Text(''),// You can add title here
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black,size: 30.0,),
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.0), //You can make this transparent
              elevation: 0.0, //No shadow
            ),),
          ]
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Color(0xFF125688),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0,0,0,0),
              child: Container(
                child: SizedBox(
                    child: FlatButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        onPressed: (){
                          onPreviousChange();
                        },
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(MyFlutterApp.left_arrow),
                          ],
                        ))
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,0,10.0,0),
                child: SizedBox(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        FlatButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          onPressed: (){
                            onNextChange();
                          },
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(MyFlutterApp.next),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

below is the client.dart file where i am saving the news using a model:

```
import 'dart:convert';

Client clientFromJson(String str) {
  final jsonData = json.decode(str);
  return Client.fromMap(jsonData);
}

String clientToJson(Client data) {
  final dyn = data.toMap();
  return json.encode(dyn);
}

class Client {
  int id;
  String newsId;
  String newsTitle;
  String newsImage;
  String newsDescription;

  Client({
    this.id,
    this.newsId,
    this.newsTitle,
    this.newsImage,
    this.newsDescription,
  });

  factory Client.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Client(
    id: json["id"],
    newsId: json["newsId"],
    newsTitle: json["title"],
    newsDescription: json["description"],
    newsImage: json["image"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "newsId": newsId,
        "title": newsTitle,
        "description": newsDescription,
        "image": newsImage,
      };
}
```

below is the database file where i am creating the database and the inserting the values in database:

```
class DBProvider {
  DBProvider._();

  static final DBProvider db = DBProvider._();

  Database _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database;
    // if _database is null we instantiate it
    _database = await initDB();
    return _database;
  }

  initDB() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "News.db");
    return await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onOpen: (db) {},
        onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
      await db.execute("CREATE TABLE News ("
          "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
          "newsId TEXT,"
          "title TEXT,"
          "image TEXT,"
          "description TEXT"
          ")");
    });
  }

  newClient(Client newClient) async {
    final db = await database;
    //get the biggest id in the table
    var table = await db.rawQuery("SELECT MAX(id)+1 as id FROM News");
    int id = table.first["id"];
    //insert to the table using the new id
    var raw = await db.rawInsert(
        "INSERT Into News (id,newsId,title,image,description)"
        " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",
        [id, newClient.newsId, newClient.newsTitle, newClient.newsImage, newClient.newsDescription]);
    return raw;
  }

  updateClient(Client newClient) async {
    final db = await database;
    var res = await db.update("News", newClient.toMap(),
        where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [newClient.id]);
    return res;
  }

  getClient(int id) async {
    final db = await database;
    var res = await db.query("News", where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
    return res.isNotEmpty ? Client.fromMap(res.first) : null;
  }

  Future<List<Client>> getAllClients() async {
    final db = await database;
    var res = await db.query("News");
    List<Client> list =
        res.isNotEmpty ? res.map((c) => Client.fromMap(c)).toList() : [];
    return list;
  }

  deleteClient(int id) async {
    final db = await database;
    return db.delete("News", where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  deleteAll() async {
    final db = await database;
    db.rawDelete("Delete * from News");
  }
}
```

Comment: I haven't use sqlite for a long time but doesn't it allow the UNIQUE keyword when creating a your sqlite table?

Comment: yes unique can be used but i want to change the icon button if data or record is 
present in the database and if it does not exists then do not change the icon button @Uni

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I can suggest on how you can approach this. You can either [check for existing entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701084/how-can-i-know-if-row-is-exist-in-flutter-sqflite) if it exists in the sqflite database, or clear the Object that you're writing to the database once the save button has been clicked once.

What happens in the code snippet that you've provided is that `_insert()` is being called regardless of the value of `isLoaded`.